# How to use ftGuid parameter type with PostgeSQL in Delphi FireDac

Tags: postgresql, delphi, firedac

I tried using

```
SELECT * FROM qrcode WHERE id = :ID
```

with parameter type ftGuid and value {6231e0a5-a0dd-461a-80f9-c3b2eb134422} and I get no records.

If I try using

```
SELECT * FROM qrcode WHERE id = UUID(:ID)
```

with parameter type ftString and same value I get a record back.

Am I doing something wrong with ftGuid?

Comment: Please show how you assign the GUID value to the parameter.

Comment: @Olivier - To assign value to the parameter I use  FireDAC Query editor. On parameter page settings for parameter :ID are: Parameter Type - ptInput, Data Type - ftGuid and Value - {6231e0a5-a0dd-461a-80f9-c3b2eb134422}. I do net get any errors, just no records. In other case I use Parameter Type - ptInput, Data Type - ftString and Value - 6231e0a5-a0dd-461a-80f9-c3b2eb134422.

Comment: Try by code: `FDQuery.ParamByName('ID').AsGUID := StringToGUID('{6231e0a5-a0dd-461a-80f9-c3b2eb134422}');`

Comment: @Olivier - Same behaviour. I think the problem is in the GUID format, FireDAC uses format with brackets but PostgreSQL do not. If brackets are ommited I get an conversion exception (for obvious reason), with brackets I get no data.